# Commit; does not work on SSIS for DB2 OleDB connection

Tags: ssis, db2, commit, rollback

I'm experiencing a problem with an OleDB connection in DB2. 
I need to include some blocks in a transaction (transaction in ssis = "Supported")
and I made a SQL Task that execute `"SAVEPOINT A ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;"`
then an other dataflow that execute some stuffs,
on success I have to commit the exec, otherwise I have to Rollback. 
But both Commit and rollback (they are SQL task) give me this error.

> "Executing the query "COMMIT;" failed with the following error: "A SQL
>   error has occurred.  Please consult the documentation for your
>   specific DB2 version for a description of the associated Native Error
>   and SQL State. SQLSTATE: 2D521, SQLCODE: -925". Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly. Task failed: Commit"

I also tried with `"SYNCPOINT"` with no success. Can anyone help me?
Thanks.